# On the differentiability of $f:\Omega \to \Bbb R,~\Omega \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ at the point $(x_0,y_0) \in \Omega$

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen a claim:

$''$A function $f:\Omega \to \Bbb R,~\Omega \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ (open) is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0) \in \Omega$ if and only if $$\delta f(x_0,y_0)=f(x_0+h,y_0+k)-f(x_0,y_0)=Ah+Bk+h\varphi(h,k)+k\psi(h,k),$$ for some constants $A$ and $B$, and the functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$ satisfy $$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}\varphi(h,k)=\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}\psi(h,k)=0.''$$

One side implication is clear for me as the linear transformation $T:=[A,B]$ from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ satisfies, $$\lim_{\lVert (h,k) \lVert \to 0}\frac{\delta f(x_0,y_0)-T(h,k)^t}{\lVert (h,k) \lVert}=\lim_{\lVert (h,k) \lVert \to 0}\frac{h\varphi(h,k)+k\psi(h,k)}{\lVert (h,k) \lVert}=0,$$ where $\lVert (h,k) \lVert=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$.

But what about the other implication:

'$f$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)~\Rightarrow \delta f(x_0,y_0)=Ah+Bk+h\varphi(h,k)+k\psi(h,k),$ satisfying aforementioned conditions' ? Is true always? If so, how to determine $\varphi$ and $\psi$? Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\dfrac{|h|+|k|}{2}\leq\sqrt{h^2+k^2}\leq|h|+|k|$.

The functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are not uniquely determined by $f$, $x_0$ and $y_0$. But you can easily construct an example:

$\varphi=\delta f(x,y)\times\dfrac{\text{sgn}(h)}{|h|+|k|}$

$\psi=\delta f(x,y)\times\dfrac{\text{sgn}(k)}{|h|+|k|}$

with appropriate exceptions for $h=0$ or $k=0$.